# Get all data from mysql display in div php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello my problem is simple , i have a table news , i have a button bt1 , and a div to show the results , i want to display all rows from table when i click the button,i only get the first row , how can i display all results ?

```
    <script>
function shownews(id) { <? php
    include('db.php');
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $a = $row['news_title'];
    } ?>
    var ab = <? php echo json_encode($a); ?> ;
    id.innerHTML = ab;
}
</script>
<div id="results"></div>
<button id="btn1" onclick="shownews(results)">See news</button>
```

Comment: You should use mysqli, mysql is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$a = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $a[] = $row['news_title'];
        } ?>
// print array

print_r($a);
```

Comment: `$a = array();` is not necessary actually - ...the $var[] behaviour where a new array is created. (http://us2.php.net/array_push)

Answer (score 1):

Your echo json_encode($a); is not in your while loop, so you only render 1 line.
Also if i understand what you're doing, you want your PHP to be executed only when you trigger your button click ? This is not the way to do it... php is a server language where javascript is executed only by your browser.

I didn't

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function shownews(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('news').innerHTML ;
    }
</script>
<div id="news" style="display:none ;">
<?php
    include ('db.php');
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     echo $row['news_title'] . '<br />' ;
    }
?>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
<button id="btn1" onclick="shownews('results')">See news</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting $a, hence you will only get the last row.

Change

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $a=$row['news_title'];
}
```

to

```
$a = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    array_push($a, $row['news_title']);
}
```

Edit: Royal_bg is correct - extra info:

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function. https://www.php.net/array_push

Answer (score 0):

You execute all the while before writing anything. Try to change the closing bracket after writing the answer...

```
<script>

  function shownews(id){

<?php

    include ('db.php');
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $a=$row['news_title'];

?>

      var ab = <?php echo $a; ?>;
      id.innerHTML += ab;

<?php

    }

?>

  }
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
<button id="btn1" onclick="shownews(results)">See news</button>
```

Comment: Two things: json_encode is not necessary since $a is just a string. And this doesn't solve the problem since `id.innerHTML=ab` will overwrite what's in the div anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function shownews(id){



  <?php
  include ('db.php');
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $a[]=$row['news_title'];

  }



   ?>


  id.innerHTML=<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;

  }
```